# Weshalb is der Satz Dativ?

Tags: dative

Ich habe die folgenden zwei Sätze:

```
"Der Gemüsehändler hat viele asiatische Lebensmittel."

"Der Gemüsehändler hat eine große Auswahl an asiatischen Lebensmitteln."
```

Der zweite Satz scheint Dativ zu sein.
Meine Frage ist, weshalb?

Comment: Der Satz ist nicht Dativ; er enthält einen Dativ, der von _an_ in der festen Verbindung _Auswahl an etw._ abhängt. Das kann man einem Wörterbuch entnehmen.

Comment: Der zweite klingt in meinen Ohren komisch. Sollte da nicht ein Genitiv hin?

Answer (score 3):

Ein Satz kann nicht im Dativ sein, Satzteile benutzen verschiedene Fälle. In

> Der Gemüsehändler hat viele asiatische Lebensmittel.

ist „der Gemüsehändler“ im Nominativ und „viele asiatische Lebensmittel“ im Akkusativ. Ebenso ist im zweiten Satz „eine große Auswahl an asiatischen Lebensmitteln“ im Akkusativ. Innerhalb dessen ist nun „asiatischen Lebensmitteln“ im Dativ, weil auf „Auswahl an“ immer ein Dativ folgt. Leider kenne ich kein gutes Wörterbuch, in dem das so deutlich steht, aber Du kannst in Wörterbüchern andere Beispiele finden.

Comment: Pons z.B. gibt immer die Fälle an: ["eine Auswahl an etw. (dat)](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=auswahl&l=deen&in=&lf=de). Listen mit Präpositionen und zugehörigen Fällen gibt es auch viele im Internet.